# Can (Should) I provide small feedback on provided code snippets, while also answering the question?

Tags: discussion

**Question**

When a user asks a question and provides a code sample, should I try to answer the question without changing his/her code too much, or can I also provide some small constructive feedback on the given code (if small enough / relevant) with an updated snippet.

**Origin**

I remember reading that SE is not meant for direct code feedback as that would make questions / answers very specific to a situation, but I do feel that some code feedback (like the example below) could increase someones knowledge.

I am talking about **answering the question first** and then have an extra note with something like 'As a hint, you could also achieve the same result with less code, making it more readable for yourself and others' and then providing a snippet with changes. (I am not talking about any personal aspects such as code conventions).

**example: (C# Unity)**

```
private void Update()
{
    StartCoroutine("Changecolor", 3f);
}
IEnumerator Changecolor()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    if(startstop == true)
    {
        int random = Random.Range(1, 4);
        if (random == 1)
        {
            m_SpriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
            m_SpriteRenderer.color = Color.blue;
        }
        else if(random == 2)
        {
            m_SpriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
            m_SpriteRenderer.color = Color.red;
        }
        else if(random == 3)
        {
            m_SpriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
            m_SpriteRenderer.color = Color.green;
        }
        else
        {
            m_SpriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
            m_SpriteRenderer.color = Color.yellow;
        }
    }
}
private void OnMouseDown()
{
    startstop = !startstop;
}
```

Which could be done with something like:

```
// store all colors in an array.
Color[] m_Colors = new Color[] { Color.blue, Color.red, Color.green, Color.yellow };

private void Update()
{
    if (startstop)
    {
        StartCoroutine("Changecolor", 3f);
        startstop = false;
    }
}

IEnumerator Changecolor()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);

    m_SpriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

    // select a random color from the array and apply it. 
    // Count() - 1 as arrays start counting at 0.
    int random = Random.Range(0, m_Colors.Count() - 1);

    m_SpriteRenderer.color = m_Colors[random];
}
```

The question I used as an example: [changing color of sprite not every frame](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/176120/changing-color-of-sprite-not-every-frame)

**final note:** My first (and last) post on GDMeta has been a while ago, so if anything about my question is incorrect / wrong, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say, the question you can ask yourself is, will others benefit by the changes? It's not only OP that people are helping by answering, but future readers as well.

I saw this answer when it was posted, and I was really confused about what it is trying to do. I agree with you that it could use a lot of work to make it readable, but if the OP is new on C# and wouldn't understand the changes, they would just ignore them.

I've seen answers before addressing this in a way to satisfy both the OP and other readers. Simply answer the question, being as straightforward as possible without altering the code a lot. After that, you can have some extra information, something like "It would be better if you did X and Y in your code, as it makes it better because of reasons A and B".

This way, the OP can read the new information, and possibly benefit from them, or just focus on the solution, which might be more time-critical for them. But future readers can see both the solution and possible ways of making the code even better.

In this specific case however, I think your code might look too complex for OP. On that question I left a comment because I'm still not sure what OP is trying to achieve.

Keep in mind there's always the [CodeReview StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), for people looking to improve their code.

Comment: So you suggest to not provide "more optimal" code, only "ways to make it better"?

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt I think showing a completely refactored code would be close to being off-topic. But advice on how to make the code better can help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

My answer will go along the lines of [TomTsagk](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2819/40264), but will end differently:

1. provide the straight answer to their question;
2. add an horizontal line (<kbd>blank line</kbd> + `---`);
3. tell them that you think of ways of making their code "more optimal";
4. describe what you think;
5. provide the code;
6. comment the code, explain what's going on.

Although they might not have a grasp of what you suggest *now*, your techniques and the code you use could get them intrigued and curious about new approaches.

Comment: I like both answers, as they are mostly the same as what I was thinking when writing this question. Making people curious about new approaches is exactly one of the main reasons as to why I would give feedback on those code snippets. I did not know (/remember) about that horizontal line, but I like that idea.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before, and typically the following applies:

- If the provided code is OK, barring that it might benefit from some refactoring, then I prefer to leave it be.  The OP might be aware of this, or doing it this way for other reasons we don't immediately know about.

  - The classic example of this in a Gamedev context might be someone who posts code using OpenGL immediate mode; a reply that focusses on "don't use immediate mode, use buffer objects", although correct and good advice, is probably actually *not very helpful* in terms of solving the problem.
- If there are other things obviously wrong with the code that would prevent the OP from achieving what they wish to do, then it would be a disservice to the OP to not at least point it out.

  - It may be appropriate to encourage the OP to ask a bunch of extra questions about these hypothetical other wrong things, rather than going down too much of a rabbit hole in your answer to their original question.

Finally, one should always remember that one may not be seeing the *actual* code in a question. Remember that:

> Questions about debugging a problem must provide a *minimal, complete, verifiable example* of the issue...

The code that is posted may therefore be this example, with idiomatic correctness perhaps being of lower priority than illustrating the problem.